# Unattached web component cannot call class methods if created before definition

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Looks like if a custom element is created before it's been defined, it will have the `HTMLElement` constructor, and retain this even after the definition is completed.

Creating that element again will have the correct constructor, see code example below.

```js
const comp = document.createElement("my-comp");

console.log('First element before definition: ', comp.constructor.name);

customElements.define("my-comp", class MyComp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { super(); }
    myMethod() { return; }
  }
);

console.log('First element after definition: ', comp.constructor.name);

try { comp.myMethod() }
catch (e) { console.error(e) }

const secondComp = document.createElement("my-comp");
console.log('Second element: ', secondComp.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you have now defined the component, you can use
`!customElements.get(comp) && customElements.upgrade(comp)` to upgrade the component so that its constructor is changed to the custom element's class.

```js
const comp = document.createElement("my-comp");

console.log('Component before definition: ', comp.constructor.name);

customElements.define("my-comp", class MyComp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { super(); }
    myMethod() { return; }
  }
);

console.log('Component after definition: ', comp.constructor.name);

!customElements.get(comp) && customElements.upgrade(comp)

console.log('Component after upgrade: ', comp.constructor.name);
```